# Local atmospheric pressure and surface gravity in Jezero crater?

Tags: mars, surface, space-probe

The Jezero crater on Mars is the target location of the American Mars 2020 mission. I can't find any good values on the local air pressure and gravity, though the elevation is around what is considered the mean sea level so I suppose the atmospheric pressure is average, around 0.006 atm (0.088 psi). The Ingenuity helicopter reportedly was tested at that pressure. Does anyone know the exact local pressure at Jezero crater's bottom and the local surface gravity? Thank you.

Comment: The answers to [How much is the difference of gravity attraction between the highest and lowest point on Mars?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/34174/12102) and [Do Curiosity's reported measurements of Mars' surface gravity (~3.717 m/s^2) include centrifugal effects?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/33961/12102) may be helpful to answers here as well.

Comment: Mars doesn't have a precise local air pressure.  It rises and falls with it's seasons and with time of day.  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:PIA16912-MarsCuriosityRover-SeasonalPressure-GaleCrater.jpg).  As a result, pressure would vary much more than gravity.  The 2020 mission is due to land on February 21, 2021 which is early Spring on Mars' Northern Hemisphere.  Early spring should be about mid-point in the range, given that Mars reaches a minimum air pressure during Northern Hemisphere summer.  No idea on time of day.